# Connecting to my Local Mac from Azure Vmware for IOS Development

Tags: macos, azure, xamarin

I have an Azure Vmware Server with VS Studio 2017 community installed.
I want to connect the VS 2017 to my Mac for IOS Development.

I have enabled the remote login on my Mac but I am not able to connect using the Mac agent
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you have a Mac already, you'll likely have a much better experience using VS for Mac than trying to use VS from a remote VM

Comment: I do have a Mac and VS for Mac Installed, But as I don't carry my MAC around, having a Cloud VM with VS installed makes it more Flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Mac agent use port 22 to connect with client computer. We need to enable this port on Windows Firewall and Network Security Group for your Azure VM.

**Steps to enable a port on Windows Firewall.**

Step 1, open Windows Firewall by inputting 'wf.msc' in Run window.

[image]

Step 2, add new rule for both inbound rules and outbound rules. In the specific port box, input 22.

[image]

**Steps to enable SSH on Network Security Group.**

Step 1, open the Network Security Group of your VM.

Step 2, add new rule for both inbound security rules and outbound security rules.

[image]

Please also make sure that your Mac machine has a public IP address and the port 22 is not disabled by any software.